# Log into Wordpress using stored username and password

Tags: ios, wordpress

Any ideas how I can approach logging into a Wordpress site using a username and password stored within an iPhone app? I am looking for a pointer in the right direction from someone who's done this before, because I didn't find many details on the web.

Comment: If you want to develop your own app, look at xmlrpc. In the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp) and I found a [tutorial](http://kovshenin.com/archives/custom-xml-rpc-methods-in-wordpress/) which might help you to start.

Comment: Thanks Alexcp - what I really want to do is set up a private Wordpress blog, and then use the app to read the blog. Hence the need for a login - I don't need to write, just read the blog.

Comment: Please add links to the resources you did find on the Web. They will help others see what you're asking about and avoid answering with something you've already seen.

Answer (score 0):

You could set your WP site to use wp_signon() ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon ) to receive the credentials and sign you in right away.

Could be something like:

```
<?php

   //First check useragent/nonce to make sure it's coming from your phone/app

   //Now get credentials and log in
   $creds = array();
   $creds['user_login'] = $_POST['usr'];
   $creds['user_password'] = $_POST['pwd'];
   $creds['remember'] = true;
   $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
   if ( is_wp_error($user) ){
      echo $user->get_error_message();
   } else {
     //do your stuff
   } 
?>
```

Not super sophisticated, but could be a start =)

Hope that helps!